# Custom "please fill out this field" box

Tags: html, css, forms

so I regularly use the "required" function in forms. So the user can't continue until they've filled out all required fields. Now I want to customize it. Because they don't fit the site I'm making at all. I know how to customize the message in it. But can I customize colors or border-radius?

PS: This is one of my input boxes (the first one)

```
<input type="text" name="vname" required autofocus oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Dit vak niet leeglaten')">
```

So I already know how to change the message inside the box. I want to style it. Like a purple border, white background, bold and purple letters. That kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the checking code and use something like jQuery or jQuery UI to add those with JavaScript.

Comment: And how would I do this? I'm not that familiar with jQuery.